Chapter abbreviation
I'm currently making my headers with fancyhdr and I'm getting overlap between the chapter and the section. Is there any way I can make like an abbreviation of the chapter title to use instead of the chapter title?

As always around here, please provide a full but minimal example that shows your problem. This may seem tedious, but the answer to your question depend on the setup of your document, as it is that setup that sends the word 'Chapter' to your headers.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please do mention which document class you employ. And, as @daleif has already asked for as well in a comment, please edit your query to (a) show the code you're using to shape the appearance of the chapter-level and section-level entries in the header line (or lines?) and (b) provide a practical example of what you call "overlap". Thanks in advance.

Both previous comments are correct -- how this is done depends entirely on the document class.  But many classes allow an alternate (usually shortened) form to be entered as an option: \chapter[<alternate>]{<full title>}.

The fancyhdr documentation, section 33 (Long chapter/section titles) gives some solutions to this problem.
